# Angular 6 setting first radio button checked does not work

Tags: angular, radio-button

I am trying to set the first radio button in a group to checked.

I have 6 tabs and have set of scales collection which needs to be displayed as a radio group buttons, and the first button should be checked by default. I am using the following code snippet in my detail component. Only the first radio button of the last tab is getting checked and the ones in the initial tabs are not getting checked. Please note the last tab is the last detail component to be loaded.

```
<div>
<div  *ngFor="let callauditscale of callauditscales; let i=index" 
class="form-check form-check-inline ">
<input  class="form-check-input" [attr.checked]="i === 0 ? 'checked' : null" 
      type="radio"  name="ExpectationOptions" 
        [id]="getOPtionbuttonId(callauditscale.CallAuditScaleCode)" 
       [value]="callauditscale.CallAuditScaleCode" >
 <label class="form-check-label" 
   [for]="getOPtionbuttonId(callauditscale.CallAuditScaleCode)">
        {{callauditscale.CallAuditScaleCode}}
 </label>
</div>    
</div>
```

How can we get the first radio button be checked in each tab. The HTML that is rendered does have each of the first radio button checked attribute in place. I did have gone through the radio button related issues previously posted in this forum and have refined my code but it is still not working

Comment: can you add your sample code in https://stackblitz.com/ so that it is easy to help you

Comment: Hi, Please find the code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9n3fyp?.The application  needs bootstrap and its dependencies. I have installed them and have linke dinthe angular.json file. Hope this will give you an idea what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The Code is broken bro

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

`[checked]="i === 0 ? true : false"`

Comment: While code only answers might provide a solution to the question, please consider explaning your code. Others might find it hard to follow or understand what the code does or why you chose this as a solution.